# Datepicker Date control does not disappear when I click outside Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, date

When i press the Date control,
and i do not enter a date,
I click Esc ==> The Date control does not disappear
I click outside ==> The Date control does not disappear
here my code html and ts :

```
<input class="cssInputDate" type="text" id="dateDebut" name="dateDebut"
#dateDebut="ngModel"
(keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
(blur)="checkDateDebut()"
required [ngModel]="dateDebutModel" (ngModelChange)="dateDebChange($event)" ngbDatepicker #ddeb="ngbDatepicker" >
<button tabindex="3" (click)="ddeb.toggle(); openDatepicker(ddeb)" type="button" style="margin-left: 0;" *ngIf="modificationMode" >
<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

here the .ts :

```
openDatepicker(id){
        console.log(" id =",id);
        console.log(" dateDebInput =",this.dateDebInput);
        this.dynamicId = id;
      }

    onClick(event) {
        if(this.dynamicId == undefined){
          console.log("Dynamic id ===",this.dynamicId);
        }
        else if(!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            this.dateDebInput.close();    
        }
      }
```

here the console log output :

[image]

any solution ?

Comment: `(blur)="checkDateDebut()"`, what does this `checkDateDebut()` do? Refering to `class="cssInputDate"` Are you using a custom date picker view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find a solution 
i use @HostListener here the code :

```
@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    mouseEvent(event) {
        if(event.target.offsetParent.tagName !== 'NGB-DATEPICKER'){
            this.dateDebInput.close();
        }              
    }
```

same of escape :

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
    keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.key === "Escape") {
            this.dateDebInput.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ere the code of checkDateDebut :

```
checkDateDebut() {
        const check = this.dateDebutModel != null && this.dateDebutModel !== '';
        const checkFinAfterDebut = this.checkDateFinAfterDateDebut();

        if (!check) {
            this.pushMessageFront('DIAG_ERR_029');
        } else {
            this.spliceMessageFront('DIAG_ERR_029');
        }

        if (!check || !checkFinAfterDebut) {
            this.highlight('dateDebut', true);
        } else {
            this.highlight('dateDebut', false);
        }
        return check && checkFinAfterDebut;
    }
```

the css :

```
.cssInputDate{
    min-width: 85px;    
}
```